# Is there a way subtract the values of one column from another column, and get the results in a new column in pandas using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I was messing around with operations in Pandas, and I reached conditional operations. For reference, I have two dataframes like this:

df_1:

| Time | Coupons_Sold |
| --- | --- |
| First_Quarter-2021 | 1041 |
| Second_Quarter-2021 | 2145 |
| Third_Quarter-2021 | 1809 |
| Fourth_Quarter-2021 | 1104 |

df_2:

| Time | Coupons_Sold |
| --- | --- |
| First_Quarter-2022 | 861 |
| Second_Quarter-2022 | 1024 |
| Third_Quarter-2021 | 902 |
| Fourth_Quarter-2021 | 1011 |

I wanted to do a conditional subtraction on these two datasets, such that the new column contains the absolute values from subtraction of the individual elements of the two columns, if and only if the time periods match.

I want something like:

| Time | Coupons_Sold |
| --- | --- |
| Third_Quarter-2021 | 907 |
| Fourth_Quarter-2021 | 93 |

because there are mappings for third and fourth quarters in both dataframes.

I tried this piece of code:

```
new_column = df_1['Coupons_Sold'] - df_2['Coupons_Sold']
```

But, this just gave me:

| center |
| --- |
| 180 |
| 1121 |
| 907 |
| 93 |

Then I tried a few conditional statements like we do in python:

`if df_1['Time'] == df_2['Time']:`

```
df_1['Coupons_Sold'] - df_2['Coupons_Sold']
```

I tried the above code with `in` keyword, but got error.

but these conditional statements just gave me errors. Is there any way to do these kind of operations(py 2.7 or py3.7, both are okay)?

Thanks in advance.

If you need any more info, please ask and I will add the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtraction is done on the row index. By default its just 0, 1, 2, etc... You could make `Time` the index of both dataframes and then the subtraction will work. You'll get a `Series` with values and `NaN`. If you want the new column to match the shape of the original dataframes, you can just use it. Otherwise, apply `.dropna()` to collapse it.

```
>>> df_1.set_index("Time", inplace=True)
>>> df_2.set_index("Time", inplace=True) 
>>> df_1["Coupons_Sold"] - df_2["Coupons_Sold"]
Time
First_Quarter-2021       NaN
First_Quarter-2022       NaN
Fourth_Quarter-2021     93.0
Second_Quarter-2021      NaN
Second_Quarter-2022      NaN
Third_Quarter-2021     907.0
Name: Coupons_Sold, dtype: float64
>>> (df_1["Coupons_Sold"] - df_2["Coupons_Sold"]).dropna()
Time
Fourth_Quarter-2021     93.0
Third_Quarter-2021     907.0
Name: Coupons_Sold, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This did work, but the column name of the new column I wanted is missing, is there a way to retain that?

Comment: This solution(modified to fit my required result) worked, and retained the missing headers:

```(df_1["Coupons_Sold"] - df_2["Coupons_Sold"]).dropna().reste_index()```

Comment: The subtraction gave you a `Series` object (the column name is `result_series.name`). The reset_index created a new dataframe. Whether that's a good thing depends on what you want to do next. Suppose this new dataframe is `df_3`. If you reference that column, as in `df_3["Coupons_Sold"]` then pandas creates a new `Series` object. You may be better off just using the `Series` object you already have. It all depends on the rest of your code, so I can't say which is the better way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `merge` + `diff` for the specific columns:

```
cols = ['Time','Coupons_Sold']
out = df1[cols].merge(df2[cols], on='Time', suffixes=('_','')).set_index('Time').diff(axis=1).abs().dropna(axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
                  Time  Coupons_Sold
2   Third_Quarter-2021           907
3  Fourth_Quarter-2021            93
```

Comment: Relatively new to pandas, but I will try this one and come back, thanks.

Comment: I tried the first of your solution, it gave me this error:

```ValueError: Can only compare identically-labelled series objects```

Comment: @YogeshSudheerModak so do they have different dimensions?

Comment: I guess so, I have just posted a small subset of the whole dataframe, but the two dataframes extend from 2011 q1 to 2022 q2, with a few values missing from both dataframes. 

For example: df_2 is missing 2013 q3 to 2014 q3, and df_1 is missing 7 quarters from 2012 to 2019. The exact number of rows on df_1 is 35 and df2 is 44

Comment: For your second solution, I'm getting:

```TypeError: Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'```

Comment: @YogeshSudheerModak I see. You have other columns then, right? I edited the answer. Please see if it works now.

Comment: Yes, there is also another column named 'ID', but I did not think it was relevent info, so i did not mention it. I'll try your edited solution regardless, Thanks.

Comment: The second solution also worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
tset = set(df1['Time']).intersection(set(df2['Time']))
df3 = df1.loc[df1['Time'].isin(tset)].merge(df2.loc[df2['Time'].isin(tset)], on='Time')
df3['Coupons_Sold']=df3['Coupons_Sold_x']-df3['Coupons_Sold_y']
df3.drop(['Coupons_Sold_x','Coupons_Sold_y'], axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Output (df3):

```
                  Time  Coupons_Sold
0   Third_Quarter-2021           907
1   Fourth_Quarter-2021           93
```

Comment: This solution also worked, but (correct me if i'm wrong), would it not use up more memory as the dataframes scaled up?

Comment: The consumption shouldn't be too much IMO. sets for the two columns and new dataframe. the .loc shouldn't take any memory, its done inplace, the drop of columns too.